# How to change the background colour of a card in Board view based on Yes/No box entry

Tags: json, formatting

Can anyone send me some sample code for the following:
I have a Yes/No checkbox called On-hold.  When this is checked "yes" I would like to colour the background of the individual card in the Board View of a Sharepoint List to Red.

I have tried this using conditional formatting but can only seem to colour the list item and not the whole card background.